# How do I adjust the timezone information when sending this iCal invite?

Tags: php, icalendar

I am trying to send a calendar request mail through my php code. I got the mail along with the calendar. But I have a problem in the start date. How to configure the start date according to Gulf Standard Time. Now I am getting according to GMT, though I did not mention anywhere. That means in short, if I will send a request on 7am then in the start date it will show 11 am.
My code is like:

```
$dtstart = $start_date_conf;

$dtend=$end_date_conf;

$todaystamp = date("Ymd\THis\Z");

//Create unique identifier
$cal_uid = date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."@fugenx.com";

//Create Mime Boundry
$mime_boundary = "----Bespot Meeting Booking----".md5(time());

//Create Email Headers
$headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

//Create Email Body (HTML)
$message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";

$message .= "<html>\n";
$message .= "<body>\n";
$message .= '<p>'.$messagess.'</p>';
$message .= '<p></p><p></p>';
$message .= '<p><b>Thanks & Regards,:</b></p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$full_name.'</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$full_address.'</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$email_address.'</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$mobile_number.'</p>';

$message .= "</body>\n";
$message .= "</html>\n";
$message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";

//Create ICAL Content (Google rfc 2445 for details and examples of usage) 
$ical =    "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:".$from_address."
DTSTART:".$dtstart."
DTEND:".$dtend."
LOCATION:".$meeting_location."
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:".$cal_uid."
DTSTAMP:".$todaystamp."
DESCRIPTION:".$meeting_description."
SUMMARY:".$subject."
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";   


$message .= "Content-Type: text/calendar;method=REQUEST;charset=utf-8\n";

//$message .= "Content-Type: text/calendar;name=\"meeting.ics\";method=REQUEST\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $ical;            

//SEND MAIL
$mail_sent = @mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: Hints: [`DateTime`](http://php.net/class.datetime), [`DateTimeZone`](http://php.net/class.datetimezone), [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: I added 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Qatar');
in the beginning of the page, but still no solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see RFC5545, you need to add a vtimezone component to refer the TZID to it

> ### Parameter Name:  [TZID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.19)

> This parameter MUST be specified on the "DTSTART",
> "DTEND", "DUE", "EXDATE", and "RDATE" properties when either a
> DATE-TIME or TIME value type is specified and when the value is
> neither a UTC or a "floating" time. ***Failure to include and follow VTIMEZONE definitions in iCalendar objects may lead to inconsistent understanding of the local time
> at any given location.***

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Qatar
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20081102T090000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0300
TZOFFSETTO:+0300
TZNAME:CST
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:mailto@organiser.net
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Qatar:20130104T090000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Qatar:20130104T100000
LOCATION:meeting_location
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:cal_uid
DTSTAMP:20130104T224617Z
DESCRIPTION:meeting_description
SUMMARY:subject
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working fine. I am getting the exact output after 2 days. Anyway, could you please tell me what is DTSTART:20081102T090000 and DTSTAMP:20130104T224617Z ?
So that I can also configure it in my code.

Comment: DTSTART:20081102T090000 is the date-time at which the asia/qatar timezone of +0300 was defined (i did not look online, just put a random date)

Comment: DTSTAMP:20130104T224617Z is the date-time in UTC coordinate when the file was created

Comment: This is not working right now, now it is getting 1 hr extra ahead. I just changed Asia/Qatar to Asia/Dubai. Sending one request at 9am from India, but it is showing at 11:30am instead of 10:30am. Should I have to change anything as I changed to Dubai? Please help me.